# CarrierWave default_url not triggering

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

I'm having a hard time getting this to work. Right now I'm using the image_tag helper on my view pages. If there isn't an image loaded, I need it to use the fallback from Carrierwave instead of just throwing an error.

For my setup I'm using fog for storage, I feel like that might be part of the problem.

```
def default_url
  asset_path("fallback/default.jpg")
end
```

Does Carrierwave just find any image that isn't set? Or is there some special way I'm supposed to grab the image url for it to work? This is what I have now.

```
<%= image_tag(property.assets.first!.image_url, :width => "200") %>
```

**Asset.rb**

```
require 'file_size_validator'
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :image_url, uniqueness: true
  validates :image_url, allow_blank: true, format: {
      with: %r{\.(gif|jpg|png)$}i,
      message: 'must be a URL for GIF, JPG or PNG image.'
  },
            :file_size => {
                :maximum => 0.5.megabytes.to_i
            }

  attr_accessible :image_url, :property_id
  belongs_to :property
  mount_uploader :image_url, ImageUploader

end
```

**Property.rb**

```
  validates :street_address, :city, :state, :description, :price, :deposit, :beds, :baths, :presence => true
  validates :street_address, :uniqueness => true
  validates :price, :deposit, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.01}

  has_many :assets, :dependent => :destroy

  attr_accessible :street_address, :street_address2, :city, :state, :zip, :country, :description, :price, :beds, :baths,
                  :deposit, :availability, :leased, :sqft, :pets
  attr_accessible :assets_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets, :reject_if => lambda { |p| p[:image_url].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
```

Comment: What error are you seeing? Can you confirm that you access the fallback image (put localhost:3000/assests/fallback.default.jpg into your browser)

Comment: I'm getting a no record error because the image_tag is looking for an image url in the db where there is none. Typing the route to the image in the browser window just gave me a routing error.

Comment: If you are seeing a no record error, that means you don't have any assets in your property. For the default_url to work, you need to create an asset without an image. btw, I spelt assets wrong above, so you should be trying 'localhost:3000/assets/fallback.default.jpg'

Comment: So let me see if I understand this. It doesn't use a default url when there is no image, it just defaults when there is a URL but not image to match it? I tried with a few different url variations in the URL and still got nothing

Comment: I'm not sure if we are on the same page, but I'll try to explain it a bit further. Let's say you have an Email model. That model has an attachment, which is one of many attributes of Email. Let's say you mount the uploader on attachment. If you create an email record, with no attachment (none uploaded), then Email.first.attachment_url will give you the default_url. If you don't have an email in the first place, then can't get the default url. In your case, the Asset is the Email, and image is the attachment. Maybe if you could give more code your problem would be clearer.

Comment: Ok, that explanation makes a bit more sense. Right now I have a property being created with no image, so it is working like your email example. I also added some more code that seemed relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Try `<%= image_tag(property.assets.first!.image_url.url, :width => "200") %>`

Let's assume you are in rails console and you have an asset with an image.  While `Asset.first.image_url` looks like its returning something like a url (assuming you are using remote storage), but its actually not a string, it's an uploader. `Asset.first.image_url.class` will return `ImageUploader`. To get the url, you need to add call the `url` method of the uploader.

Comment: This didn't work. Any other ideas? <%= image_tag(property.assets.first!.image_url.url, :width => "200") %>