# Carrierwave `default_url` not triggering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I'm trying to get carrierwave to display a default image for records that do not have any images uploaded.

I'm using carrierwave default code. Under app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb:

```
def default_url
  ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
end
```

I have my default image "default.png" stored within assets/images/fallback.

In my views, I'm using the image helper tag:
    <%= image_tag @listing.images.first.url %>
Note: `@listing` being an instance of record

For records that have an image, it is displayed without a problem. For records that do not have an image, I get an error "undefined method `url' for nil:NilClass".

In byebug placed in views:

- For records that have image: `@record.images` returns an array with
  image filename within it.
- For records without image: `@record.images` returns an empty array.

When byebug is placed within `default_url`, it is not triggered at all when records without images were accessed.

[full code]
app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

# Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  # storage :file
  storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  def default_url(*args)
    # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
    ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))

    # "/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  # process scale: [200, 300]
  #
  # def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
  # end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_limit: [200, 200]
  end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  def extension_whitelist
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  # def filename
  #   "something.jpg" if original_filename
  # end

end
```

Related View:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <%= image_tag @listing.images.first.url %>
</div>
```

Comment: Try def default_url(*args) please

Comment: add puts in default_url action to know it is called

Comment: @artgb `default_url(*args)` did not make any difference. `puts` command within `default_url` was not called.

Comment: Could you send me full code/jsfiddle for analyzing?

Comment: @artgb edited to include full code

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15239412/carrierwave-default-url-not-triggering